# Check if record exists in python. If exists then skip else process

Tags: python, csv

I have a function for extracting frames from videos. I have a csv file which has the names of the videos already processed. I want to check if the name of a newly added video file is present in the csv file. If present then exit the code else process the function to extract frames from the new video

```
def extractFrames(m):
    global vid_name

    vid_files=glob(m)

    for v_f in range(len(vid_files)):
        print("path of video========>>>>.",vid_files[v_f])

        #latest_file=max(vid_files, key=os.path.getctime)

        #print(latest_file)

        v1=os.path.basename(vid_files[v_f])     
        try:
            vid_name = os.path.splitext(v1)[0]

            vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_files[v_f])
        except cv2.error as e:
            print(e)
        except:
                print('error')
        #condition 
        fsize=os.stat(vid_files[v_f])
        print('=============size of video ===================:' , fsize.st_size)
        try:

            if (fsize.st_size > 1000):

                fps = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)      # OpenCV2 version 2 used "CV_CAP_PROP_FPS"
                frameCount = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
                duration = frameCount/fps
                minutes = int(duration/60)
                print('fps = ' + str(fps))
                print('number of frames = ' + str(frameCount))
                print('duration (S) = ' + str(duration))
                if (duration > 1):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()


                    count=0

                    success=True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"

                        success,image = vidcap.read()
                        if count % 10 == 0 or count ==0:
                            target_non_target(img_name, image)

                        count+=1          

                    vidcap.release()

                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        except:
            print("error")


        print('finished processing video ', vid_files[v_f])
        with open("C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs"+'/video_info.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
            fieldnames = ['Video_Name','Process']
            file_is_empty = os.stat("C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs"+'/video_info.csv').st_size == 0
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            if file_is_empty:
                writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow({'Video_Name':vid_name,'Process':'done'})

if __name__ == "__main__":

    x="C:\\Python36\\videos\\*.mp4"

    extractFrames(x)
```

Suppose a folder has 2 videos V1 and V2 from which frames have already been extracted and the names V1 and V2 are added in the csv file. Now when i add video V3 the code should check if V3 exists already in the csv. If it exists then the code should be skipped else frames from V3 should be processed and V3 should be added in the csv file after extraction of the frames

Comment: What output does your code currently give, and what you are expecting it to output?

Comment: I'm not sure opening a csv file like that will work like you intend it to. Try using the `pandas` module. I use it when I have to automate stuff with csv files.

Comment: So, you want to look up the `vid_name` first, before processing? Would a list of done `vid_names` help? (Can you read your csv into a list?)

Comment: @JerryM. Currently my code processes all the video files present in the folder. i want it to extract frames from only the newly added video files and not from the already processed old videos

Comment: @doctorlove a list of vid_names will really help. I was actually looking to do the same but the issue is where shall that part be written? How can i access the vid_name inside the main function? Can you help me out with the writing part a bit? It would be really kind of you

Comment: @JerryM. Any luck?

Answer (score 1):

Without the details you have code like this

```
def extractFrames(m):
    # do stuff
    vid_files=glob(m)

    for v_f in range(len(vid_files)):
        #find vid_name
        #do stuff
        save_as_done(vid_name)

if __name == '__main__':
    x="C:\\Python36\\videos\\*.mp4"
    extractFrames(x)
```

If you pass in a list of things that have been done, something like

```
done = ['first.mp4', 'second.mp4']
```

you can check if a filename has been done like this:

```
>>> 'first.mp4' in done
True
```

So, if you save the filenames (fully pathed) of what you've done to a file and load them into a list, like this

def load_done_list():
    with open('video_info.csv') as f: #or full path, maybe pass in the file name?
      return f.readlines()

you can check the list

```
def extractFrames(m, done):
    # do stuff
    vid_files=glob(m)

    for v_f in range(len(vid_files)):
        #find vid_name
        if vid_name not in done:  #,--- check if done already
            #do stuff
            save_as_done(vid_name)

if __name == '__main__':
    x="C:\\Python36\\videos\\*.mp4"
    done = load_done_list() #<--- You need to load this into a list
    extractFrames(x, done)  #<--- and pass it in to your function
```

This need something that just saves the filenames as they are done:

```
def save_as_done(vid_name):
    with open('video_info.csv', 'a') as f: #maybe pass in the file name so you only define it once?
        f.write(vid_name + '\n')
```

I haven't filled in all the details, but have shown where you can do loading and saving and checking. 
The written file only has the filenames in - there doesn't seem much point in having "done" on the end of each line.
This will keep opening and closing the file as the files are processed. This may slow thing down but might not matter: you could pass in a file handle to write to, to keep it open. You have options.

Comment: but that is the whole issue i am facing. How can i access my csv_file from the function inside the __main__ part. You can edit my code as well. This is the whole function which needs no other details. The csv_file has the names of the done videos

Comment: can you please help me with this issue? i have done exactly as above but unable to access my csv file inside main function

Comment: That's almost a new question. What goes wrong when you try to open the file? Do you want help writing the function?

Comment: I have my function written but i am not able to use the csv file created inside "__main__" for checking the video file names. How can i do that

Comment: please see my updated code below as per your idea. Is my approach correct?

Comment: I'm not sure where your updated code is. I'll add a file read and write that's as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need a function to get the list completed/done videos from the csv file.
Something like this, might need to tweak a bit for the header row.

```
def get_completed_videos():
    completed_videos = []
    with open(".../video_info.csv") as csv_file:
        for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
            completed_videos.append(row[0])
    return completed_videos
```

Then exclude them in the extracting func

```
def extractFrames(m):
    global vid_name

    vid_files=glob(m)
    complete_videos = get_completed_videos()
    new_vid_files = [x for x in vid_files if x not in complete_videos]

    ...
```

Comment: But i already have made the csv file in my function to save the names of the video files. I just need to access it for checking if the video file name already exists in the csv or not. How can i access my csv file inside the main function without creating a new function for it?

Comment: Function is just to organize the code. In the main function, you can use the same code provided above to open the said file, and use csv.reader to get a list completed videos.

Comment: Well i tried adding the code as suggested but i am getting a bit confused and facing errors.Can you please add your suggestions in my actual code function given above?

Comment: I made a seperate function below extractFrames and passed the 2 lines inside extractFrames. But the square brackets give me the error of invalid syntax

Comment: I edited the answer, that should fix the invalid syntax error

Comment: can you please have a look at my edited answer below as per your suggestion? Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
def extractFrames(m,done):
    global vid_name

    vid_files=glob(m)

    for v_f in range(len(vid_files)):
        print("path of video========>>>>.",vid_files[v_f])

        v1=os.path.basename(vid_files[v_f])
        vid_name = os.path.splitext(v1)[0]

        if vid_name not in done:
            try:
                vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_files[v_f])
            except cv2.error as e:
                print(e)
            except:
                print('error')
        #condition 
            fsize=os.stat(vid_files[v_f])
            print('=============size of video ===================:' , fsize.st_size)
            try:

                if (fsize.st_size > 1000):

                    fps = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)      # OpenCV2 version 2 used "CV_CAP_PROP_FPS"
                    frameCount = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
                    duration = frameCount/fps
                    minutes = int(duration/60)
                    print('fps = ' + str(fps))
                    print('number of frames = ' + str(frameCount))
                    print('duration (S) = ' + str(duration))
                    if (duration > 1):
                        success,image = vidcap.read()


                        count=0

                        success=True

                        while success:

                            img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"

                            success,image = vidcap.read()
                            if count % 10 == 0 or count ==0:
                                target_non_target(img_name, image)

                            count+=1          

                        vidcap.release()

                        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            except:
                print("error")


            print('finished processing video ', vid_files[v_f])
            with open("C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs\\"+'video_info.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
                fieldnames = ['Video_Name','Process']
                file_is_empty = os.stat("C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs\\"+'video_info.csv').st_size == 0
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                if file_is_empty:
                    writer.writeheader()
                writer.writerow({'Video_Name':vid_name,'Process':'done'})

if __name__ == "__main__":

    x="C:\\Python36\\videos\\*.mp4"

    y="C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs\\video_info.csv"

    done=list(y)
    extractFrames(x,done)
```

Comment: @ Anh Do Hoang is this what you were suggesting to do? If yes, then this code still does not check for the presence of video name in csv. It processes all the videos in the folder. Is my approach correct?